# Storing HSET using springboot RedisCacheManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

I am trying to create and delete a cache using RedisCacheManager with spring-boot and want to use HSET programmatically but am unable to do it. I am able to do it as a simple SET but not as HSET.

This is the bean that I have created

```
    @Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisCacheConfiguration config = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig() //
        .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(1)) //
        .disableCachingNullValues();

    return RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory) //
        .cacheDefaults(config) //
        .build();
```

And even made the class where I am making the call as @RedisHash but no luck.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RedisHash(value = "CURRENT_CALLS")
public class CacheCleanupService implements Serializable {

    @CacheEvict(value = "CURRENT_CALLS" ,key = "(#cacheKey)")
    public void redisCacheNumberCleanup(String cacheKey) {
        log.info("Key CLEANUP from the cache: {}", cacheKey);
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "CURRENT_CALLS", key = "(#cacheKey)")
    public String redisCacheNumberStore(String cacheKey) {
        log.info("Key Add from the cache: {}", cacheKey);
        return cacheKey;
    }
}
```

The o/p I am getting is this when calling these above methods from another @Service class.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys CURRENT_CALLS:*
1) "CURRENT_CALLS::+15109100689:+15134631989"
2) "CURRENT_CALLS::+15109100648:+15134631989"
3) "CURRENT_CALLS::+15109100688:+15134631988"

127.0.0.1:6379> get "CURRENT_CALLS::+15109100648:+15134631989"
"+15109100648:+15134631989"
```

However, I want the o/p like this

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys CURRENT_CALLS
1) "CURRENT_CALLS"

127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall "CURRENT_CALLS"
1) "+15109100648:+15134631989"
2) "1"
3) "+15109100688:+15134631988"
4) "2"
5) "+15109100689:+15134631989"
6) "3"
7) "+17326667726:+17722915819"
8) "4"
```

Not sure how will I be able to store it in HSET rather than simple SET in redis.Even @RedisHash didnt help.

Is there any way to achieve the hash of set or delete i.e HSET or HGET through annotations of springboot. I could achieve it by template but not by annotations. With annotations I am able to store normal cache in redis but not hash. Please help.